# Can the application know whether the Home button or the Power button was pressed?

Tags: ios, methods, background, ios5

If either of buttons is pressed, both ApplicationWillResignActive and ApplicationDidEnterBackground methods are being called.
I want my application, on its way to the background, to respond differently to these buttons.
Can that be done?
The problem is only in iOS 5. In previous versions of iOS, only ApplicationWillResigActive was called.
Thanks

Comment: i've got the same problem here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229392/ios5-background-management-different-from-ios4