# iOS12: Is there any way to know whether app was left via Home button or Lock Screen button?

Tags: swift, ios12

Issue is what ApplicationWillResignActive() and ApplicationDidEnterBackground() are called just the same regardless of how app was left.

Previous versions of this questions have been asked and answered ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754317/is-it-possible-to-distinguish-between-locking-the-device-and-sending-an-app-to-b) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896095/can-the-application-know-whether-the-home-button-or-the-power-button-was-pressed) ) but do not seem to apply to iOS 12 (testing on device not simulator). I know apps that do it so there's a way. Thanks a ton !!

Comment: The answer is NO, IMHO any apps detecting this are using private APIs, I'm curious what apps have this behavior ?

Comment: Hi @Mosbah, Forest (https://www.forestapp.cc/) is one example, as 
User locks screen -> session keeps going
User presses home button -> session stops .

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46002893/9576580) looks related, check for screen brightness when `applicationDidEnterBackground(_ :)` and handle accordingly.

Comment: it's related, but doesn't work on iOS 12, i've tried and it returns "Home button " every time... :(